# Nested When Statement in kotlin complaining about missing lamda empression

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using Nested when statements there is a case. Below is the code:

```
 fun validateNewPinData(newPin: String, confirmPin: String, oldPin: String, isOldPinVisible: Boolean): Byte {
    return when {
        newPin.isEmpty() -> ValidationErrorType.NEW_PIN_ERROR
        confirmPin.isEmpty() -> ValidationErrorType.CONFIRM_PIN_ERROR
        newPin.length < Constant.THRESH_HOLD_PIN -> ValidationErrorType.NEW_PIN_THRESH_HOLD_ERROR
        confirmPin.length < Constant.THRESH_HOLD_PIN -> ValidationErrorType.CONFIRM_PIN_THRESH_HOLD_ERROR
        newPin != confirmPin -> ValidationErrorType.MISS_MATCH_PIN_ERROR
        when (isOldPinVisible) {
            oldPin.isEmpty() -> ValidationErrorType.OLD_PIN_ERROR
            oldPin == newPin -> ValidationErrorType.SAME_OLD_NEW_ERROR
            getSavedPin() == newPin -> ValidationErrorType.IMMEDIATE_OLD_PIN_ERROR

            else -> ValidationErrorType.NO_ERROR
        }

        else -> ValidationErrorType.NO_ERROR
    }
}
```

Compiler is complaining before last else part to add missing lambda expression. I was wondering even if this possible to accomplish this thing with Nested whens? There is an alternate inside when there can be if-nested if as well. My question is why it is asking for missing lambda? Even is this possible to do with nested? Any help would be highly appreciated.

EDIT: For reference or clear understanding, I am adding screen shot of the Error.

[image: Picture of error can be seen here]

Comment: If you can avoid nested 'when' then you should consider that, else you can move the nested when of another the function and use the values returned from it, check this https://rules.sonarsource.com/kotlin/RSPEC-1821

Answer (score 1):

You should probably move the nested `when` into the `else` branch. Inside a `when` there cannot be a line that doesn't belong to a branch. And in your code, the way the compiler sees it, the nested `when` doesn't belong to any branch, therefore it's invalid format.